# Checkbox not Checked in Modal Load

Tags: .net

I have a modal with a checkbox, and I want to pre-check the checkbox based on a condition. Here's the relevant HTML and JavaScript code:

HTML:

```
<!-- Status-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="status" for="radio_status" class="col-form-label">Estado: </label>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_status" id="input_tarjetaCredito_status_a" value="A" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="input_tarjetaCredito_status_a">Activo</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_status" id="input_tarjetaCredito_status_i" value="I">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="input_tarjetaCredito_status_i">Inactivo</label>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var tarjetaCredito_status = $("#input_tarjetaCredito_status_a").is(':checked') ? $("#input_tarjetaCredito_status_a").val() : $("#input_tarjetaCredito_status_i").val();
```

I want to pre-check the checkbox with the ID flexSwitchCheckDefault based on the tarjetaCredito_status variable. However, even though the variable holds the correct value ('A' or 'I'), the checkbox is not being checked when the modal is loaded. What could be the issue, and how can I resolve it?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I want to pre-check the checkbox with the ID flexSwitchCheckDefault based on the tarjetaCredito_status variable. However, even though the variable holds the correct value ('A' or 'I'), the checkbox is not being checked when the modal is loaded. What could be the issue, and how can I resolve it?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You mentioned a checkbox with the ID flexSwitchCheckDefault, but it isn't included in the HTML you provided.